# How can I invoke php files through apache2 with getting a 403?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Using apache2 and some php (specifically grav) I'm getting a permission (403) problem when I try to explicitly invoke a php file such as `phpinfo.php`. I've found lots of similar questions and they recommend looking at the permissions and user of the php file. The thing is I already have `index.php` in that directory and it seems to be working fine. My website is basically running okay. I'm just trying to add some new php files to it. Here's a dir listing showing the permissions on both `phpinfo.php` and `index.php`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 shayne shayne 1500 Jun 13 16:57 index.php*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 shayne shayne   23 Jun 13 16:57 phpinfo.php*
```

I note that I have a user/group that isn't `www-data` but I can't change that easily (okay, I can, I don't want to for maintenance reasons). I checked `.htaccess` and that doesn't mess up the path (I used the [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/) for that).

I can't get at the config files because this is on BlueHost and they don't let me go there so my options are limited. I also can't see the apache logs. There is nothing in the local logs (`./logs` and `./error_log`)

Also I have replicated the whole thing on my local machine and `phpinfo.php` gets invoked just fine, and there I have fewer permissions on `phpinfo.php` ie `-rw-rw-r--` (no x) as well as a different user/group.

Anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong here, especially if `index.php` is working. It is possible that there is a rule in the config files that you can't touch that blocks files called `phpinfo.php`. Try renaming that file and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular as I said, I don't have access to config files. I do have access to .htaccess but that seems okay. I tried a different file name and got the same result.

Comment: Ok - another guess. Your host has used the [disable_functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive in PHP to disable `phpinfo()` and possibly other internal functions. Since you can't execute `phpinfo()` to list the contents of PHP.INI you'd have to contact the support people at your host to verify this.

Comment: So can you add files other than your `index.php`, suppose `test.php`, with any PHP code that executes successfully? If yes, then what the others said, this is a security restriction from your hosting provider.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular the support people pointed out I had a upper dir with an .htaccess. Removing that fixed it. Kind of embarrassing but problem solved. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: @MarkusAO Only index.php worked, others didn't. The support people pointed out I had a upper dir with an .htaccess. Removing that fixed it. Kind of embarrassing but problem solved. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: We facepalm our way to success. At some point, the radar will be picking up most all possibilities and the level of routine embarrassment decreases.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be a .htaccess file I had not noticed in an upper directory. That had some rules in it I do not need and removing it cleared up the problem instantly. Otherwise it would have been config that I could not access.